# How to find the words after a space?

Tags: string, lua

I would like, to know in lua, how can we do that :

```
local test = "Hey Hello World"
local extract = string.match(test, "I don't know what to put here")
print(extract)
```

Result = Hello World

I tried with

```
local test = "Hey Hello World"
local extract = string.match(test, "^.*%s(.*)")
print(extract)
```

But the result = "World"

Comment: Do you mean this? `extract = string.match(test, " (.+)")`.

Comment: No, I want to get everything after the first space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lua
local test = "Hey Hello World"
local extract = string.match(test, "^.*%s(.*)")
print(extract)
```

is almost correct, but somewhat overcomplicated. The result is just `"World"` because it won't get everything after the *first*, but rather everything after the *last* space because the first `.*` is greedy - it will match as much as it can. Your pattern could be fixed if you just used `.-` instead, which will match as few characters as possible: `"^.-%s(.*)"` yields the desired result.

Your pattern can however be simplified significantly by just omitting the `^` beginning pattern anchor as Lua patterns always go from left-to-right and `(.*)` will be a greedy match to the end: `"%s(.*)"` will provide you the string after the first space character (can be empty). If you want to allow double spaces, you have to use a quantifier for the first spacing: `"%s+(.*)"`.

lhf's pattern `" (.+)"` is also an option, assuming a simple ASCII space   and assuming that you want the returned match to be a nonempty string or `nil`.